# How can you specifically extend an automorphism from a quadratic field to one of a cyclotomic field?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions, cyclotomic-fields

I am trying to see how can I extend the automorphisms of the Galois extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})/\mathbb{Q}$, for $d$ square-free, to automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}$ that fix $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, when $n$ is given so that  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ .

I've found a result that tells me how $n$ has to be: if $d\equiv 1 \mod 4$ then $n$ can be taken as a multiple of $|d|$ and in other case as a multiple of $4|d|$ (where $|\cdot|$ is the absolute value).

Right now my progress is the following: I know that $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})/\mathbb{Q})$ only contains the trivial automorphism and the one that sends $\sqrt{d}$ to $-\sqrt{d}$, and I have read that if $d<0$ then these automorphisms can only be extended to the trivial one and the one that acts as complex conjugacy respectively (but I don't understand this) and I want to know why and what happens if $d>0$.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, the claim in the last paragraph is simply false. The field $L=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ has $\phi(n)$ automorphisms. The restriction of each and every one of them to $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$ is either the identity or the other automorphism. Basic Galois theory says that both alternatives occur equally often. Namely, those extending the identity of $K$ are exactly the automorphisms in $Gal(L/K)$, and there are $\phi(n)/2$ of those. Irrespective of the sign of $d$.

Comment: That also gives you the recipe for extensions. $Gal(L/K)$ is an index two subgroup of $Gal(L/\Bbb{Q})\simeq \Bbb{Z}_n^*$. To get a handle of that I would resort to the old "Chinese Remainder Theorem is your friend".

Comment: I can post an answer tomorrow, if we agree on an interpretation of the question :-)